# Pandas read csv with double char text qualifier

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file (which I cannot alter from source) that is as such:

```
||Month||,||Year||,||EntryId||,||ReportId||,||ElementId||,||AgreementId||,||MonthNum||,||DerivedDate||,||Hours||,||Count||,||Hours||,||Sub||
||January||,||2010||,||1||,||1||,||122||,||159||,||1||,||2010-01-01||,||441905||,||0||,||0||,||0||
||February||,||2010||,||1||,||1||,||122||,||159||,||2||,||2010-02-01||,||443440||,||0||,||0||,||0||
```

I am trying to get this into a Pandas Dataframe but struggling to get the separators ot work correctly.

Is this actually possible? I have to read the file in chunks too as it is pretty big so I've been reading it in in lines of 10000 before writing it out.

Attempts...

```py
with open('File.csv') as f:
    dfs = pd.read_csv(f,
                     sep=",",
                     quotechar='\|\|',
                     na_values=['null', 'none'],
                     engine='python',
                     chunksize=1000)
for x in dfs:
    print(x.columns)
```

Result:
`TypeError: "quotechar" must be a 1-character string`

```py
with open('File.csv') as f:
    dfs = pd.read_csv(f,
                     sep="\|\|",
                     na_values=['null', 'none'],
                     engine='python',
                     chunksize=1000)

for x in dfs:
    print(x.columns)
```

Result: A lot of empty columns...

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
from io import StringIO

with open('./test_quotation.csv', 'r') as txt:
    txt = txt.read()

# you can complete the other arguments:
# na_values=['null', 'none'] and chunksize=1000
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt.replace('||', '')), header=0, sep=',', skipinitialspace=True, engine='python')
```

Output:

```
>>> print(df)

      Month  Year  EntryId  ReportId  ElementId  AgreementId  MonthNum DerivedDate   Hours  Count  Hours.1  Sub
0   January  2010        1         1        122          159         1  2010-01-01  441905      0        0    0
1  February  2010        1         1        122          159         2  2010-02-01  443440      0        0    0
```

Note: You get a column named Hours.1 because there are 2 different columns named 'Hours'